# PHP -> JSON Response, Wanting To Filter By Key Word - 500 Error?

Tags: php, json, strpos

PHP->JSON

So I'm calling an online service that returns a JSON to which I'm decoding. Then for each record, I'm STRPOS against one field, and if !== FALSE, I want it to display the record, else go to next record.

ISSUE: Without the STRPOS, all the code works and doesn't timeout. With STRPOS, I'm getting a 500 error.

Is it my code (inefficient) or is the service timing me out maybe? Thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

```
$jsonFile = file_get_contents('https://api.website.com/file.json');
$json_outputa = json_decode($jsonFile);

foreach ( $json_outputa->divisions as $division )
{   

$jsondeal = file_get_contents('https://api.website.com/specifics.json?division_id=' . $division->id . '&filters=category:' . $category . '&limit=20');

$jsondeal_output = json_decode($jsondeal);

foreach ( $jsondeal_output->deals as $deal )
{
    If ($deal->tags)
    {
        If (strpos($deal->Title, $searchstring) !== false)
        {
            ?>
                    <tr>
!! NOW DO STUFF !!
```

*! The Code that works and returns to the UI. Just the IF with STRPOS removed.

```
$jsonFile = file_get_contents('https://api.website.com/file.json');
$json_outputa = json_decode($jsonFile);

foreach ( $json_outputa->divisions as $division )
{   

$jsondeal = file_get_contents('https://api.website.com/specifics.json?division_id=' . $division->id . '&filters=category:' . $category . '&limit=20');

$jsondeal_output = json_decode($jsondeal);

foreach ( $jsondeal_output->deals as $deal )
{
If ($deal->tags)
{
           ?>
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful to see the exact different code between what is working and what isn't. Do you simply replace `strpos($deal->Title, $searchstring) !== false` with `true`? Do you remove the entire condition and any commands within it?

Comment: Thanks for responding @Patrick. The code change is simple, just the removal of the IF with STRPOS. See above.... (Sorry didn't realize I can't line return here).

Comment: Check your error logs. Status code 500 is almost always accompanied by a logged error.

Comment: [14-Sep-2016 16:49:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/garagekid/public_html/group/index2.php on line 111
[14-Sep-2016 16:49:41 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/garagekid/public_html/group/index2.php on line 111

Comment: @PatrickQ In review; could this invalid argument be an empty json possibly?

Comment: Empty or just not what you expect it to be.  `var_dump()` would come in handy here

Comment: Var_Dump of the JSON or the searchstring (or both?) ... I haven't used var_dump() before so feel free to educate me a little more :)

Comment: @PatrickQ - Here is my attempt; `Notice: Undefined variable: deal in /home/garagekid/public_html/group/index2.php on line 113

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/garagekid/public_html/group/index2.php on line 113
string(4) "taco" NULL string(4) "taco" string(50) "Wings at Cat & Fiddle Sports Pub"....`

Answer (score -1):

I think its is your link https://api.website.com/file.json
try opening it in browser it says 404 file not found.

try a local json or something valid JSON file like this one

http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cbvSOJYRbC?indent=2

Comment: Yes, I changed the original api address for generic words instead of specific. So yes, it'll return 404 for you. Not me. :)

Comment: Oh ok sorry my bad i should have guessed

Comment: I'm a little confused by strpos returns true for false for first occurrence? If it's not found at all wouldn't false be the correct response?

Comment: I have edited my content I was just trying to help can you please remove the down vote